# Dependency of MISRA-C coding rules checker to the compiler

Tags: c, misra

I have started using a tool allowing to check the compliancy to MISRA-C 2012. The tool is Helix QAC. During the configuration it requests to select one compiler. My understanding is that MISRA-C (and coding rules in general) are not linked to a compiler toolchain, since one of their objective is portability. Moreover one rule of MISRAC is to not use language extensions (obviously this rule may be disabled or there may be exceptions to it). Helix documentation or support is rather vague about this (still trying to get more info from them)  and just mention the need to know the integer type length or the path of standard includes. But the rules analysis should be independant from `int` size and the interface of standard includes is standard so the actual files should not be needed.

What are the dependencies between a MISRA-C rules checker and the compiler ?

Comment: I think it's not very clear exactly what you are asking.

Comment: "What do you think ?" is too broad.  What is the problem?

Comment: What dependencies are there between a MISRA checker and a compiler is a rather specific question, if you just drop the "What do you think?" at the end.

Comment: Given that your question is "Why does this MISRA-C checker tool need to know which compiler I use?", my question to you is "Why do you care that the tool wants to know which compiler you use?". Unless you are asking this just out of curiosity (and that's legit), but your question may only be fully answered by the tool's developer, I'm afraid.

Comment: QAC does not only check MISRA rules but also other rules. We are using an older version of QAC, and the project configuration contains a "compiler personality" file with various settings for a specific toolchain. This file also contains a reference to an include file which (I think) contains macros and pragmas to prevent QAC warnings for system include files or compiler builtins. These file may be project/company specific, but QAC also contains default "compiler personality" files for several compilers.

Comment: @LucaPolito it might be quite some effort to configure your MISRA checker for your compiler. If there is no template/configuration provided for the version you are using, you will have to spend extra time. It would reduce the effort if there was no need for that.

Comment: The reason i'm asking is that : 1) I'm working in a highly constrained environment where every tool and tool configuration must be explained and justified 2) as @Gerhardh said, it is not obvious to configure the checker for the compiler (and be sure the result is correct)

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean MISRA-C in itself (5.3.2) also requires that you document how you configure the static analyser, what things you have set it to ignore and why etc. Ironically, I see now that this text in the MISRA guide lines makes the very same example of essentially boolean type as I did in the answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the Guidelines depend on knowing what the *implementation* is doing - this is particularly the case with the *implementation defined* aspects, including (but not limited to integer sizes, maximum/minimum values, method of implementing *boolean* etc)

MISRA C even has a section **4.2 Understanding the compiler** which coupled with **4.3 Understanding the static analysis tool** addresses these issues.

Comment: Indeed, the section 4.3 answers partly to my question as it states : "The documentation for each static analysis tool being used on a project should be reviewed in order to understand How to configure the analyser to match the compiler’s implementation-defined behaviour e.g. sizes of the integer types (...)". I

Answer (score 2):

There is one thing every MISRA-C checker needs to know and that's what type you use as `bool`. This is necessary since MISRA-C:2012 still supports C90 which didn't have standard support for a boolean type. (C99 applications should use `_Bool`/`bool`, period.) It also needs to know which constants that false and true correspond to, in case `stdbool.h` with `false` and `true` is unavailable. This could be the reason why it asks which compiler that is used. Check Appendix D - Essential types for details.

Type sizes of `int` etc isn't relevant for the MISRA checker to know. Though it might be nice with some awareness of non-standard extensions. We aren't allowed to use non-standard extensions or implementation-defined behavior *without documenting them*. The usual suspects being inline assembler, interrupts, memory allocation at specific places and so on.  But once we have documented them in our deviation to Dir 1.1/Rule 1.1, we might want to disable warnings about using those specific, allowed deviations. If the MISRA checker is completely unaware of a certain feature, then how can you disable the warning caused by it?

Comment: I do not know nor used the Helix QAC tool, but I do know that many tools provide additional features/checks (beyond MISRA-C ones), so that may be a reason why the tool needs information about `int` size, for instance.

Comment: @LucaPolito Yes that's true too, they generally check for a lot of things outside MISRA-C (if they are any good).

Comment: @Lundin so you mean that a compiler would define `bool` itself even when configured in C90 ?

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean Yes there was commonly some non-standard extension in embedded systems C90 compilers, where you could find some home-brewed boolean type in some header file. Though in retrospect the comment by Luca above is likely the main reason why the tool wants to know the compiler, so it's not necessarily for MISRA-C purposes at all.